# Cannot retrieve xml data with IMPORTXML in Google Sheets

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am trying to retrieve and parse xml data from the following URL using

```
=IMPORTXML("https://monitoringapi.solaredge.com/site/894123/sensors?startDate=2020-10-01%2000:00:00&endDate=2020-10-06%2000:00:00&api_key=MGTH4B2W39EJ8O433GSMRNQHRY0WKF9C";"/siteSensors/data/telemetries/sensorsTelemetry")
```

or

```
=IMPORTXML("https://monitoringapi.solaredge.com/site/894123/sensors?startDate=2020-10-01%2000:00:00&endDate=2020-10-06%2000:00:00&api_key=MGTH4B2W39EJ8O433GSMRNQHRY0WKF9C","//date | //globalHorizontalIrradiance")
```

I keep on getting the error message 'Imported XML content cannot be parsed'.

I've checked the xpath in an online xpath tester and it returns data fine.

When i put the URL in a browser window I do indeed receive the XML (which curiously has a script element at the end....)

All help most gratefully appreciated,

Best regards  /Colm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra `&format=xml` to your URL:

`=IMPORTXML("https://monitoringapi.solaredge.com/site/894123/sensors?startDate=2020-10-01%2000:00:00&endDate=2020-10-06%2000:00:00&api_key=MGTH4B2W39EJ8O433GSMRNQHRY0WKF9C&format=xml";"//siteSensors/data/telemetries/sensorsTelemetry")`

It looks like the API gives Google Sheets JSON data by default. According to the Solaredge API [docs](https://www.solaredge.com/sites/default/files/se_monitoring_api.pdf), you can specify the format as json, xml, or csv. (The docs say you want `application/xml`, but this didn't work for me.)

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you for reading the docs better then I did.

Comment: @carbontracking Eh, I can't fault you for thinking that it returns XML data based on what you get when pasting it into the address bar. Probably some user-agent check on the site or something. Go figure.